# Express, dynamically load content on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

My question is, I would hope, a very easy one to answer.
I have a html page written in in some template/template engine(in my case its ejs).

When the user sends a get request the page is loaded and the user has a bunch of "things" he can click on to get new content. This content is delivered from a database and from a folder and I have the <%= %> fields in my .ejs file that I'm serving so that I can load in the content using an express controller.
However, whenever I wish to change the content on the page (as a result of a user get request), I have to load the whole page again. I'd like to only load the new/changes <%= > fields from the ejs template.

I'd prefer to do this whole process server side OR if I am to include files for this on the users side I'd prefer to limit myself to some simple javascript or changes in my HTML and not go through the whole process of integrating Angular or React with my application.

Comment: Once the page is load you can use JavaScript to manipulate your DOM throught HTML tags if get request don't force the page to load again. ( XMLHttpRequest, ajax, ...)

Comment: Could I used those XMLHttpRequest to query a database (monogoDB in this case) ? Also, would it be considerably slow than doing it server side ?

Comment: AJAX 's the man for the job  here

Comment: Yes, you can define in your route handler a route to query mongoDB and send the results in JSON. Then use it in your ajax call to get the JSON and manipulate DOM. I think is faster and cleaner than reload the entire template page.